# If spouse is not righteous wat should we do

Tags: islamic-scholar

Assalamualaikum..

In today's post of Dr. Zakir Naik on Facebook is as below

"Surrounding yourself with righteous people is one of the best ways to increase Imaan.

If your friends don't pray, eventually you will stop praying. If they keep looking at Haram, eventually you will look at that Haram. Friends affect your life whether you notice it or not."

So here my question is,
keeping righteous people like friends keep us closer to Islam is okay, but if husband is not righteous what should we do, as being a female who is weak can't leave her husband nor can be with him because of many reasons like what society say, who will take care of her kids, parents are poor who can't afford her and her kids upbringing etc.

In such a situation what does she has to do please

Jazakallah hu Khaira

Answer (score 0):

As'salaamu alaikum, ukhti.

I am familiar with brother Na'ik's work and I respect his teaching to a very high degree. I think the brother's advice was offered more as a general rule of thumb than as an iron-clad principle that should always be followed.

Yes, we do TEND to be influenced by our friends. Positive friends tend to influence us positively; negative friends tend to influence us negatively. That is true, but it is only a tendency -- it's not something that is ALWAYS true. Sometimes WE are the influencers in the relationship, for better or worse.

Prophet Ibraheem (alaihi salaam) is called an excellent example for us to pattern ourselves after, (Qur'an 16: 120-122). He resisted the negative influences of his entire society, including that of his own father. The Prophet Muhammad (A.S.) is also described as an excellent role model (Qur'an 33: 21), and he also resisted the negative influences of his society and family EVEN BEFORE HE RECEIVED HIS PROPHETHOOD. He just wasn't into the stuff that his people were into.

Now, a marriage is a very intimate relationship. And you're right -- there is a powerful desire to please and bring joy to our mates. Even in that situation it's not a foregone conclusion that we will allow our spouses to negatively influence us.

Consider Surat-ut-Tah'rim (66), ayah 10 and 11. In this passage allow tells us about the wife of Pharoah and the wives of Prophets Lot and Noah (A.S.). Pharoah's wife was a righteous woman even though her husband was, without doubt, an evil AND powerful man. The opposite is true of Noah and Lot's wives. Their husbands were righteous men (chosen Prophets of Allah!) but they were nevertheless evil woman.

At the end of the day it's going to boil down to ikh'laas and 'azm. Ikh'laas is your loyalty and devotion to Allah and His Deen. 'Azm means determination. ANYONE who is determined to remain loyal and devoted to Allah and his Deen will not be negatively influenced by anyone. Period. Even the Shaytaan knew that.

"(Iblees) said, 'My Lord, because You have put me in the wrong, I will make (wrong) alluring to them on earth, and I will put them all in the wrong -- EXCEPT YOUR SERVANTS, THE MUKH'LASEEN (those who have ikh'laas).' (Allah) said, 'THAT IS THE WAY THAT LEADS STRAIGHT TO ME." Surat-ul-Hijr (15), ayah 39-41.

Thus, while it is true that we can be negatively influenced by our friends and loved ones, with ikh'laas and 'azm we can TRANSCEND their peer pressure and continue being true to Allah and His Deen. That is Grace and Favor from Allah.

Now, if you're in a situation where your husband FORCES you to partake in his wrongdoing with him, and it's not feasible for you to just up and leave him (because you need him), in that situation it is very likely that Allah will forebear with you and forgive you for the wrongs he compels you to indulge in.

Allah knows best.

Dr. Na'ik is right, when possible and feasible we should not keep company with bad people. In Surat-ut-Tawbah (9), ayat 119 Allah Himself tells us, "O' you who Believe! Fear Allah, AND BE WITH THE SADIQEEN (those who stand true to Allah and his Deen)." If we hang out with people who are strong in the habit of praying, it will be easy for us to develop prayer as a habit; if we hang out with people who show kindness to others, we will find it easier to be kind ourselves; and the same is true for all other virtues -- hanging out with people who possess those virtues will make it easier to develop those virtues in ourselves.

However, if you are stuck in a situation to where you HAVE to stay with a bad person, all is not lost. Hold  fast to ikh'laas and 'azm, MAKE ALLAH YOUR INFLUENCING FRIEND, and He will empower you to transcend that situation you are stuck in. He may even give you a way out of that situation. All things are possible by the Power and Grace of Allah. Alhamdulillah!

Insha'Allah, this answer helped you.

Maa'as'salaam.

Comment: Jazakallah hu Khaira

Comment: Alhamdulillah, sister.